# Qt button arrangement with fullscreen Camera view

Tags: python, pyqt, qml

im currently working on a small startup for some extra cash, im using qt 5.13 and my aim is to develop a small camera with functions like dimensional measurement based on the lense and height or edge detection and that sort of thing, these i will be developing in python with the use of opencv.

Anyways my question is this, before i dive in too deep to go back, is it possible to use qt, to run a (Pi)camera fullscreen, no edges and just have a small transparent button on a corner to be the settings? Like, this for sake of the UX, i wouldnt like to have borders or to need to cut screen size to add features.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt, all cameras will be equal, so you can prototype it on your PC first, and it should work on RPi. Using QML, it should work just fine - it's a compositing framework that uses the GPU for composition, and RPi 4 has plenty enough GPU bandwidth to deal with it. QML supports semitransparent controls.

You may wish to see various augmented reality (AR) measurement applications available for iOS and Android (even just the Ruler included in iOS 12). You might be entering a crowded market. Those apps are not perfect, and there are simple cases that throw them off - like measuring the size of a window on a large flat wall on the side of a long but narrow room - there's too much bloom and not enough detail on the wall to have a stable depth reference, even on the best iPhone available.

If you can write software that is extremely robust, then you'll have a real market differentiator - but it won't generally be easy, and OpenCV is only a low-level building block. It's not unthinkable that you'll need some GPU-oriented computational framework instead (OpenCV provides some of it, but it's far from general).

Also, 99% of the UX will be the software, and that software should be very much portable by design, so investing anything in hardware before your software is good is a waste. Just as you suggest, a RPi 4 will do great for prototype hardware - but there's a catch that you may be limiting yourself unnecessarily by tying it all to a platform. There's so many platforms that settling on RPi when there's no market need for that is not sensible, I don't think.

You could use one of a multitude of WiFi battery-powered cameras with your PC: this will let you concentrate on the algorithms and functionality without having to mess with cross-compilation for RPi, etc. It'll also let you develop good software even if an RPi won't have enough bandwidth to do this realtime processing. There are faster platforms, so it'd be best not to get invested in any hardware at all. The quality of the camera will matter a lot, though, so you will want to start with a good WiFi camera, get things perfect, and then downgrade and see how far you can go. Even professional cameras provide WiFi streaming, so you can use a camera as good as you can afford. It will make things simpler to start with.

Also, don't spend time on the UI much before you get the core functionality solid. You'll be designing a "Debug" UI, and you perhaps should keep that one available but hidden in the final product.